# How to get the 'file's name' of image selected

Tags: ios, iphone, image, uiimageview

I'm trying to get the file's name of the image selected with this code:

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    img = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [self.imgFoto setImage:img];

    NSURL *imagePath = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];
    NSString *imageName = [imagePath lastPathComponent];
    NSLog(@"image name is %@", imageName);

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

But all i see is:

[image]

I mean, I shouldn't be like `IMG_00001.jpeg`, `IMG_00002.jpeg`, etc. ?

Greetings.

Comment: This is not related to Xcode (the results and the problem would be the same if you used `emacs` and `make` to write your program). As to what it "should" be: if it's always the same, then it's always the same. This is an implementation detail, and there's no reason to try assuming anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

Use AssetsLibrary as below lines of code

```
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>
```

Than

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info

 NSURL *refURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *imageAsset)
{
ALAssetRepresentation *imageRep = [imageAsset defaultRepresentation];
NSLog(@"[imageRep filename] : %@", [imageRep filename]);
};

// get the asset library and fetch the asset based on the ref url
ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetslibrary assetForURL:refURL resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:nil];
```